# VB.NET to C# conversion (Dictionary(Of String, Object))

Tags: c#, vb.net

I need assistance converting this VB to C#. The VB isn't very well designed though.

```
Public Shared ReportGrid As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
Dim DataGridData As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
DataGridData = ReportGrid("GridData")
```

ReportGrid is populated with another dictionary's contents.

Please can someone assist? Thanks

Comment: We are not your online code converters. What is this code supposed to do, what part are you having trouble with and what did you try, did you [read the manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)?

Comment: You need to use `Option Strict`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
public static Dictionary<string, object> ReportGrid;
Dictionary<string, object> DataGridData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
DataGridData =  (Dictionary<string, object>)ReportGrid["GridData"];
```

You can use this converter http://converter.telerik.com/

In VB.Net if you do not do `Option Strict On`, then conversion is implicit. However in C# you have to do the conversion explicitly if implicit conversion does not exist.

Comment: @why negative. Please explain.

Comment: should use `var` on the second line.

Comment: @Jodrell: Did casting on that. Look at updated answer.

Comment: you can still use `var` on the second line, although you have compensated for the lack of strict typing in the OPs code.

Comment: @Jodrell: Is that wrong?

Comment: the first is subjective but I think var is closer to the VB, the later is correct. (I'm not the downvoter.)

Comment: @Jodrell - the omission of `var` is not wrong, it is a convenience syntax that allows the type to be inferred. It is actually confusing to those that do not understand how it works, so it could be argued that it is, sometimes, bad to use, especially if it is not obvious what the right-side of the assignment is doing.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal. Thanks for the quick response. This has helped me towards solving the problem.

Comment: @KarlAnderson, can we agree that `Dim` is as meaningful as `var` and all .Net developers must understand the this aspect of `New` and `new`. (lets not consider shadowing inherited members.)